# Can't properly install Django-requests module

Tags: django

I followed the steps in this doc: https://django-request.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Except step 4, which I'm not sure what it means: "Make sure that the domain name in django.contrib.sites admin is correct. This is used to calculate unique visitors and top referrers."

However, I get this error, when I try to load my app:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: request_request
```

Here is the what happens when I run python manage.py migrate:

```
Operations to perform:
 Apply all migrations: admin, auth, catalog, contenttypes, djcelery, sessions
 Running migrations:
 No migrations to apply.
```

Answer (score 1):

Error you are getting and Step 4 are not really related to each other.

Step 4 is related to proper tracking of [domain by Sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.Site.domain) framework, while the error you are getting is because Django is unable to find the table `request_request`.

If you go back to step 2, they have asked to run migrations which will create the table for you.

> Run manage.py migrate so that Django will create the database tables.

It seems like the migration was not run to create the tables. Can you run `python manage.py migrate` from project root and post the terminal output here?

Comment: I ran the migrations. I even deleted all my migrations and reran the python manage.py migrate and it has not worked. I have Django 2.2.3

Comment: Can you check your DB if the table is created already? Just to be doubly sure, can you also run `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate` to check if DB is in consistent state?